# Fastest and/or safest way to concatenate two wide strings in c++?

Tags: c++, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

Is one of the following wide string concatenation methods faster and/or safer than the other?

1) std::wstring

```
LPCWSTR str1 = L"string 1,";
LPCWSTR str2 = L"string 2";

std::wstring stdResult = std::wstring(str1) + str2;
LPCWSTR result = stdResult.c_str();
```

2) wcscpy_s, wcscat_s

```
WCHAR buf[128];

LPCWSTR str1 = L"string 1,";
LPCWSTR str2 = L"string 2";

wcscpy_s(buf, str1);
wcscat_s(buf, str2);
LPCWSTR result = buf;
```

3) _snwprintf_s

```
WCHAR buf[128];

LPCWSTR str1 = L"string 1,";
LPCWSTR str2 = L"string 2";

_snwprintf_s(buf, _TRUNCATE, L"%s%s", str1, str2);
LPCWSTR result = buf;
```

or is there a faster/safer method?

Of these, what is the best option in terms of:

- Speed
- Security

Comment: Whenever possible use `std::wstring` as it takes care of buffer allocation and release. Option 2 and 3 have the potential for overflow if you're using user data, which is super bad.

Comment: but what about speed? is std::wstring slower than the other ones? Speed is very important for my usecase

Comment: The only way to know for certain is to profile it.

Comment: Speed doesn't matter if you're leaking memory all over the place or have massive buffer overflow bugs. That being said, as Nathan hints, profile it. Test under the most extreme conditions you can to learn more about the performance characteristics. Speed can be "important" but that doesn't mean  you need the absolute fastest solution, you just need something acceptably fast and `wstring` is good at what it does. Faster solutions may be UTF ignorant and can cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: ... and you need to profile your final code, of course. Switching between `LPCWSTR` and `wstring` forth and back might not be necessary at all if you stick to `wstring` throughout; and you would have the benefit of move semantics and safer memory management. Note, for example, that `LPCWSTR result = stdResult.c_str();` may easily lead to UB once `stdResult` is manipulated afterwards or goes out of scope.

Comment: it depends what are you doing how you use result string. Versions 2 and 3 are turbo fast since they do not allocate on heap. Also it is possible to create C++ class which will be as fast as no heap version and will be more flexible then C versions.

Comment: @SinOfficial Try not to take a downvote as personal criticism, though I did not downvote I am pretty sure that the downvotes are not because you do not know the answer but because the question asks for an opinion. A question asking for an opinion [violates the type of question that is wanted on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), there are other sites that appreciate questions asking for opinions.

Comment: @Geronimo So speed and security are considered subjective opinions? If you only read the title of the question it sounds like a opinionated question but if you read the whole question it is clear that speed and security is asked for, which is defenetly not asking for opinions.

Comment: I edited the title to make it more clear that speed and security are the properties of the methods that i want to know

Comment: @SinOfficial not bad, I would suggest losing the word "recommended" in the text also. It invites a discussion and argument which is more of a forum type posting as opposed to Q&A which allows for a definite answer. The question is now `on hold` which means it will get reviewed again and the `close` can get overturned.

Comment: @SinOfficial Gonna propose a change to the Q that I would consider passable, you can always roll it back if you don't like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The examples are not proper.
For example, in your `wcscat` variation, there is no additional memory allocation, so it is as rapid as it will ever get.

When doing a `+=` on a `std::wstring`, speed mostly depends on whether `std::wstring` will have to reallocate.

Therefore, your problem reduces to the memory allocation issue. If there is memory allocated already, then `wstring` should perform as fast as you would need.

The other issue is what others have noticed already, that you want *reasonable* speed and *maximum* safety. If you plan on too many concatenations and your profiler shows significant speed issues, then you can implement your own allocator.

Comment: `std::wstring` has `reserve` so you can work around the risk of reallocation.

Comment: Yes, I 'm trying to indicate him that his problem is the memory allocation issue, not the copying speed.

Comment: and `wstring` maintains a `length`, with might be an advantage compared to the speed of `wcscat`

Comment: My application currently uses method 3 and i dont know if it is worth replacing it with 1 or 2. I dont know if std::wstring is worth the (potential) speed loss because due to the origin of the strings it is impossible for the buffer to overflow and my application is working with audio data and every milisecond is worth gold.

Comment: @SinOfficial I'm a professional audio developer and I had never issues with STL, working with ASIO buffers with super low latency and VSTs. You can cope with std::wstring, speed is too high for PC audio nowadays. Even if that means recording from 32 channels.

Comment: @Michael Chourdakis Im trying to optimize every line of my code to get the lowest latency possible, especially because im using a FFT. But i think probably right, it wont make such a big difference anyways. Thanks for your answer to this question.

Comment: FFT is enough fast for considering all these.